# How do I add my images for my app icon in Xcode 6.1?

Tags: xcode

I keep getting this warning that says the size of the images are wrong and I know there right. I set one of them  to 180x180 and put it in the 3x 60 pt iPhone App IOS 7,8 and it says "the size of the image is 196x193 but should be 180x180." Why does this happen?

Comment: If you do a right-click "Get Info" of the image file in the finder what does it report? How did you set the size to 180x180?

Comment: it says 196x193...I dont get it I set the height and width to 180x180. Am I setting the size wrong or something? This is my first time doing this so I dont know what Im doing wrong.

Comment: Im  using sketch and in the side theres a panel for height and width and I set the height and width to 180x180.

Comment: Your graphics program might export things like shadows that are outside of the canvas. It should have an option to limit the export to the size you have specified.

Comment: I don't use sketch but it is clear that what you are doing is not calling the image.

Comment: Maybe that helps: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/24691/sketch-export-layers-and-keep-the-layer-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is the wrong size.

To verify the actual size of the image right-click "Get Info" on the image file in the finder.

The image needs to be scalled in an image editing program, I use Graphic Converter. There are other graphic programs which will also work.

Comment: Are there any free ones?

Comment: [Graphic Converter](http://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/download/) has a free demo period, get it. It is developed by a single developer on his own, he has been supporting and upgrading the program for over a decade.

Comment: Okay I'll try that one.